# Kendo UI copying data through controls

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to take 2 separate Kendo UI grids and be able to pass data back and forth through UI controls (like forward and backward arrows)?

The pattern would would be to take the master list on the left, select items and have a refined list on the right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If is possible and it is not hard to do but you have to do it by yourself so you need:

1. Some knowledge on KendoUI `Grid` and `DataSource` and the events that they expose.
2. Some knowledge on JavaScript + jQuery that help you with the validations and avoiding errors.

Lets have the following grid definitions:

```js
var grid1 = $("#grid1").kendoGrid({
    dataSource:  ds1,
    selectable:  "multiple",
    navigatable: true,
    pageable:    false,
    columns:     [
        { field: "name", title: "Name" },
        { field: "lastName", title: "Last Name" }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");

var grid2 = $("#grid2").kendoGrid({
    dataSource:  ds2,
    selectable:  "multiple",
    navigatable: true,
    pageable:    false,
    columns:     [
        { field: "name", title: "Name" },
        { field: "lastName", title: "Last Name" }
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

We define two buttons:

1. for copying selected rows from `grid1` to `grid2`
2. for copying selected rows from `grid2` to `grid1`

The button definition is:

```html
<div><a href="#" id="copySelectedToGrid2" class="k-button">&gt;</a></div>
<div><a href="#" id="copySelectedToGrid1" class="k-button">&lt;</a></div>
```

And the JavaScript for managing it:

```js
$("#copySelectedToGrid2").on("click", function (idx, elem) {
    moveTo(grid1, grid2);
});

$("#copySelectedToGrid1").on("click", function (idx, elem) {
    moveTo(grid2, grid1);
});
```

Finally the `moveTo` would be something like:

```js
function moveTo(from, to) {
    var selected = from.select();
    if (selected.length > 0) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(selected, function (idx, elem) {
            items.push(from.dataItem(elem));
        });
        var fromDS = from.dataSource;
        var toDS = to.dataSource;
        $.each(items, function (idx, elem) {
            toDS.add({ name: elem.name, lastName: elem.lastName });
            fromDS.remove(elem);
        });
        toDS.sync();
        fromDS.sync();
    }
}
```

Example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2qXKy/)

Comment: wow, that is super cool. Thank you so much! what would be the best way to get up to speed on all that you mention. Is there a good tutorial series? I know the basics but the above is a little over my head :-)

Comment: Official [Getting Started](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/what-is-kendo) is not bad at all we all miss it going directly to the api documentation. [This](http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/inheritance-with-kendoui) is also promissing. Finally KendoUI Evangelist [blogs](http://www.telerik.com/community/evangelists/burke-holland.aspx) and why not, mines too ;-)

Comment: How can I implement this using Kendo UI asp.net MVC wrappers?

Comment: If you set `pageable:   true`, it's not working correctly, the number of items displaying is not good.

Comment: @OnaBai it is possible to put a single line to the other grid with a double click?